# Adding Class to first child of a group of parent elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I've searched hi and low and after too many hours staring at the rest of this codebase, the answer to this seemingly simple function is eluding me.

HTML is as follows:

```
<a class="element-link local" data-category="local">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48/eee/eee.png"  class="logo" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="element-link local" data-category="local">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48/eee/eee.png"  class="logo" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="element-link news" data-category="news">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48/eee/eee.png"  class="logo" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="element-link news" data-category="news">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48/eee/eee.png"  class="logo" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="element-link business" data-category="business">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48/eee/eee.png"  class="logo" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="element-link business" data-category="business">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48/eee/eee.png"  class="logo" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="element-link business" data-category="business">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48/eee/eee.png"  class="logo" alt="" />
</a>
<a class="element-link business" data-category="business">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/48x48/eee/eee.png"  class="logo" alt="" />
</a>
```

What I'm trying to do is target the first child of each one of the categories, and to add a class to it. So, the FIRST news, business, etc. (for each category) will have a class added to it. For example this is the JS I have:

```
$container.find('.element-link').each(function(){
    var category = $(this).data('category'); 
    $(this).hasClass(category).first().addClass('new');
});
```

I have tried various iterations of :first, :first-child, :eq(1) to no avail., and I'm out of coffee to boot.

Any help is greatly appreciated!
Thanks.

Comment: BTW your `<a>` are missing required `href` attribute

Comment: `hasClass` returns true/false, not a chainable object

Comment: You might consider using a `background-image` for `.element-link` instead of embedding images in every single one

Comment: @Madbreaks pls explain.. I understand it returns boolean, but it seems like I've used it before in this way: if hasclass() then ...

Comment: @Ejay, thanks.. this was just example code.. actual code has href,. good catch

Comment: @Madbreaks.. thanks for the image advice,. but they are avatars, this is just example code..

Comment: You can't call `first()` on a Boolean

Answer (score 2):

`hasClass`returns `true` or `false`, so you cannot chain it further with `.first()`.

Said so, you should cache all the links, then filter them:

```
var $links = $container.find('.element-link');

$links.each(function(){
    var category = $(this).data('category'); 
    $links.find('.' + category).first().addClass('new');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of achieving it

```
        //get all unique "category" values
        var cats = $.unique($('a.element-link').map(function(){
           return $(this).data('category')
        }).get());

        //add classes to first element of each "category"
        for (var x =0; x < cats.length; x++){
           $('a.element-link[data-category="'+cats[x]+'"]:first').addClass('new');
        }
```

Comment: +1 You beat me too it.  I'd like a `for(var i in cats)` better than a standard `for` loop but hey, that's just me.  I think this is a superior approach because it does not require iterating over all `.element-link` elements.

Comment: thanks. And there's still some room for optimization by caching `$('a.element-link')` ;)

Answer (score -1):

Maybe my code is not nice but should work.

```
var oldCategory = '';
$container.find('.element-link').each(function(){
    var category = $(this).data('category');
    if(oldCategory != category)
        $(category).addClass('new');
    oldCategory = category;
});
```

Comment: -1 Too brittle. While this might work for the given code sample, it assumes categories are always grouped and would fail if there is any overlap. In addition it's inefficient, looping over all `element-link` elements

Comment: But in this case it will work. I answer for this question with this specified html code. You have right in comment but shouldn't minus me.